# Dafny cannot prove that 'a^2<=b^2*c^2' implies 'a<=b*c' for reals greater than 0

Tags: z3, theorem-proving, dafny, square-root

I want to test the following property in Dafny: `a^2<=b^2*c^2` implies `a<=b*c`. It automatically checks this for (positive) integer numbers:

```
lemma powersVSsquares_integers(a:int, b:int, c:int)
   requires a>=0 && b>=0 && c>= 0
   ensures (a*a <= b*b*c*c) ==> (a<=b*c)
   {}
```

Now, I want to test this for real numbers, so I try:

```
lemma powersVSsquares_reals(a:real, b:real, c:real)
   requires a>=0.0 && b>=0.0 && c>=0.0
   ensures (a*a <= b*b*c*c) ==> (a<=b*c)
   {}
```

But Dafny cannot prove this. Thus, I start with the case where `a>=1.0 & b>=1.0 & c>=1.0`:

```
lemma powersVSsquares_reals1(a:real, b:real, c:real)
   requires (a>=1.0 && b>=1.0 && c>=1.0)
   ensures (a*a <= b*b*c*c) ==> (a<=b*c)
   {
     assert a <= (b*b*c*c)/a;
   }
```

But not even `assert a <= (b*b*c*c)/a`; can be proven. So I have no idea on how to deal with this prove.

Can anyone provide lemma `powersVSsquares_reals` proven in Dafny? Can this be done without defining a symbolic square root function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will need some axioms of the reals that are not readily available in Dafny.

```
lemma increase(a: real, b: real, x: real)
  requires x > 0.0
  requires a > b
  ensures a * x > b * x
{
}


lemma zero(a: real)
  requires a*a == 0.0
  ensures a == 0.0
{
  if a != 0.0 {
    if a > 0.0 {
      increase(a, 0.0, a);
      assert false;
    } else if a < 0.0 {
      increase(-a, 0.0, -a);
      assert false;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use these axioms to do a regular proof. Here I choose the style of a proof by contradiction

```
lemma powersVSsquares_reals(a:real, b:real, c:real)
   requires a>=0.0 && b>=0.0 && c>=0.0
   ensures (a*a <= (b*b)*(c*c)) ==> (a<=b*c)
   {
  if a*a <= (b*b)*(c*c) {
    if a == 0.0 {
      return;
    }
    if b == 0.0 || c == 0.0 {
      zero(a);
      return;
    }
    assert a*a <= (b*c)*(b*c);
    if a > (b*c) {
      assert b * c > 0.0;
      increase(a, b*c, b*c);
      assert a * (b*c) > (b * c) * (b*c);
      assert a > 0.0;
      increase(a, b*c, a);
      assert a * a > (b * c) * a;
      assert a * a > (b * c) * (b*c);
      assert false;
    }
    assert a<=b*c;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, it is perfect. I did not know that Dafny was not considering some basic axioms such as `a*a==0` implies `a==0`. By the way: which is the difference between a Lemma with the `axiom` keyword and without it? It seems to me that a (not verified) lemma is exactly like an `assume`, so I cannot elucidate what does `axiom` add.

Comment: `{:axiom}` makes the compiler happy. Otherwise, if you don't declare a lemma as `{:axiom}` and try to compile the code and don't have a body for the lemma, the compiler will complain.

Comment: Understood. However, this is really strange for me: I thought that the reason for the compiler not to produce code was precisely that using `assume` (or an empty lemma) yielded that this code was potentially 'not synthetisable/implementable'. What does internally change with `{:axiom}`?

Comment: By the way, I was able to prove zero() from the other lemma.

Comment: assume statements, unless they also have {:axiom}, won't make the compiler happy. So it's similar.

Comment: I was also able to add a body to `increase` and Dafny proved it.

Comment: Yes, what it makes me confuse is why should we use `axiom`. I thought that an `assume`/empty lemma implied that (compilable) code could not be constructed, because it could be the case that specification was not correct. I mean, how can we create a code that ensures one thing and the contrary, for instance? I do not know if I explain myself :(